# Assign variable using string content in R

Tags: r

I have a string like that

```
mystring<-"A+B+C"
```

a data where A, B and C as varialles.
How do I get this into a command like

```
x<-A+B+C
```

using mystring as above.
Thanks for any hint

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval` and `parse`

```
A <- 1
B <- 2
C <- 3
x <- eval(parse(text = "A+B+C"))
x
## [1] 6
```